# .NET Core API - IIS - cannot make it work

Tags: iis, .net-core, visual-studio-2019, http-status-code-503

I created a simple **.NET Core API** with **Visual studio 2019**

I just cannot make it work

I go from **503** to **404** to **connection refused**, and so on...

**I tried** :

- adding my app to an application pool with or without SSL and dev certificate
- publishing the application in a folder and setting that folder in IIS like in many tutorials
  then VS2019 complains about that and force the IIS site to be linked to the VS project root
- I set bindings to 80 and 443 ( modded my host file to have fqdn of the web site to point to 127.0.0.1
- I checked the IIS logs and I even added a Failed Request Tracking rule on port 503, no log file was ever produced, while the error clearly appeared
- I tried by setting the wwwroot of the site to ../bin/debug or .../bin/release

**launchSettings.json**:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iis": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://*******-api.local",
      "sslPort": 0
    },
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:55973",
      "sslPort": 44362
    }
  },
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "weatherforecast",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "IIS Local": {
      "commandName": "IIS",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "weatherforecast",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "*********Api": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "weatherforecast",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What's stopping you from creating a new solution and copy-pasting the code you added to it? If you have version control, you can go back to the moment it still worked.

Comment: it's a brand new fresh solution, I did not even modified it

Comment: Could you show us the code in `Startup.cs` and `Program.cs` file?

Answer (score 0):

- I deleted my project, recreated it,
- I also installed the **windows hosting bundle**
- also make sure the .NET CLR Version is set to **No Managed Code**

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/thank-you/runtime-aspnetcore-3.1.6-windows-hosting-bundle-installer